# Kali Linux Kex no longer recognizes my password

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, login

One day I wake up, I start my WSL kali-linux (by typing "kali" and "kex --esm" to start the remote desktop), The Remote Desktop decides that my password isn't correct anymore.
My account password works fine when i try to switch to sudo. I simply cannot connect from RDP:

[image]

This is NOT the first time it happened to me before, I had to uninstall the whole WSL system and Kali to resolve (uninstalling `kex --purge` is not enough).

PS:"kex" (without "--esm") works fine, but it is inconvenient to work with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is an RDP connection problem, many ppl had it. I doubt it is about password.

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

Kali is a collection of penetration Apps and very short on friendliness and user tools. It is not meant as a WSL App.

WSL is not very good at being a true Virtual Machine App.

So, if you wish to run Kali, put it in a good Virtual Machine App. I use VMware Workstation.

If you need WSL instead, get Ubuntu from the Microsoft Store to run in WSL.

Match Apps with a good Strategy .

I use Kali V2023.1 in VMware Workstation which supports USB Pass Through.

Comment: VirtualBox is for free...

Comment: True but VBOX is not an efficient VM app.  It works, just not the best

Comment: I was never able to install VMware correctly so that i can easily copy-paste between OS and transfer files(idk if it's me or what). Working with wls is so easy.

Comment: See why VMware does not install. It installs fine here and is very efficient.